# fiber optic face plate physics-opaque to transparent behavior based on distance of object?

Tags: optics, visible-light, fiber-optics

Please look at this video below. its of fiber optic plate or compressed fiber lens

Here it seems that the object- which is the book or letters here, is visible only when the plate is touching the letters. Once the lens is lifted, it behaves as though its opaque.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUlow0-5pWU

Even the picture of the same fiber optic plate in hands behaves similarly- at-least while looking at its picture.

Here too, only the finger print or the ridges of the finger print that are on physical contact with the plate are visible as though the fiber optic plate is transparent. The rest of the finger is almost not visible.

http://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachgebiete/baudisch/projects/3d_tracking/fiberio/2013-uist13-fiberio-fingerprint_faceplate.jpg

It seems that the fiber optic plate behaves as opaque plate or very translucent till the object touches the plate. is this true? will the fiber optic plate behave like this when views from any direction? Can some one please explain physics behind this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the light that originates at a period (full stop, '.') on a page.  If the face plate is right up against the page, the light from that period will enter only a few fibers, those that are in contact with the period.  If you lift the plate from the page, the light from the period spreads out before it hits the plate.  If you move the plate far enough (only a centimeter or so) the light from that period will enter *all* of the fibers, and come out *all* of the fibers on the other end.  You will have lost the image completely.

The plate has to be very close to the page, a technique known as "proximity focusing".

Comment: Thanks @garyp.

is there any way of making such a surface with alternate methods? basically I want a touch activated opaque to transparent surface.

Comment: Say I have a transparent plastic or acrylic sheet which has two surfaces - A and B. What I am looking for is a manner in which I can make one surface-(A) of that sheet look opaque white (by light scattering) But when I touch or say press opposite surface (B) of that sheet, with any other another object say my hand then the light scattering should not happen at all and I should very clearly-in full fidelity- be able to see my hand from surface A . Again if I take my hand off that opposite surface (B) I should only be able to see white surface (A).

Comment: Liquid crystal shutters can be made to do something like that.  Google the term; you'll get dozens and dozens of hits.